# Adding files from folder to the list in android app

Tags: java, android, list, file, android-sdcard

I'm trying to create a list of files in my sdcard (and then get a random one from this list).
I've read tutorials but none of those worked.

My code is as following:

```
    try{

    File file=new File("/sdcard");
    File[] list = new File ("/sdcard").listFiles();
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File f : list){
         if (f.isFile()){
          if (f.getName().startsWith("aa")){
            lista.add(f.getName());
                                           }            
                        }
                       }
    Random gen = new Random();
    String s = lista.get(gen.nextInt(lista.size()-1)).toString();
    wyswietl.setText(s);

    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        Log.e("nope", e.getMessage());
    }
```

LogCat shows exceptions.

I've checked every single line - when I try to show lista.size() - it throws ResourcesNotFoundException.
What interesting is, changing String s into

`String s = lista.get(1).toString()`

works - it shows me one of the files in the folder.
So my question is: how can I fix this and get a list of files (which start with "aa") in /sdcard folder?

Comment: `LogCat shows exceptions.` Mind to add your **full** logcat?

Comment: plz add your full logcat

Comment: Now I've changed gen.nextInt(lista.size()-1) into gen.nextInt(lista.size()) and there is nothing in the logcat but my problem stays the same - it adds only one file into the list (and it should add many).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pick one random item in array list, I believe it should be

```
String s = lista.get(gen.nextInt(lista.size()));
```

Random.nextInt(int n) retrieves random value between 0-(n-1). See [Random.nextInt() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29).

ResourceNotFound exception I believe is related to failure to locate resource ID inside R.java not index out of bound exception.

TextView.setText() with integer value parameter, interprets integer value as a resource ID, [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29). So if you call

```
atextView.setText(lista.size());
```

It will throw ResourceNotFoundException because it may not point to correct resource ID. If you want to display number of items in list then

```
atextView.setText(String.valueOf(lista.size()));
```

Comment: thanks for it - there is nothing in the logcat now. But my problem stays the same - only one file is added to the list, so random works pretty the same like lista.get(1).toString().

Comment: lista is ArrayList<String> instance so you do not need to call lista.get(intvalue).toString(); lista.get(intvalue) should suffice. Are you sure lisa.size() greater than 1?

Comment: It should be. I'm desperated now so I put my files in assets, res/raw and main app folder. In each there is more than one file which begins with 'aa'. And every time I start my app it gives me one and the same text.

Comment: When you debug, how many array returned by this statement File[] list = new File ("/sdcard").listFiles(); ?

Comment: If you know there are many files that should be returned by listFiles() but in reality there is only one that returned, it may related to file permission. In your code, items in lista only grow when you have a file (not directory) and start with name 'aa'.

Comment: where can I change these permissions? Does it depend of file extension?

Comment: I've found something creepy. It came out that the code works on the virtual machine but it doesn't work on any phone. I don't understand it but apparently it isn't this function's fault.

Answer (score 0):

If lista.size ()  equals 0  then exception can occur...
( because gen.nextInt (-1) )

I hope you to prevent it.

Comment: but lista.size() cannot equal 0 because lista.get(1).toString() works so there is something inside. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the different way to the filter on list of file based on file name !!!!

```
File f = new File("/sdcard");
    String fileList[];


    if(f.isDirectory()){
      fileList = f.list(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                if (name.startsWith("aa")){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

'FileList' is an array where you get all the File object and then you can easily get the file name from that!!!!
Hope this will help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution why this code didn't work. The files weren't in the folder yet - i had to add names to the list manually, then in other function check if they are on sdcard (if not, there is need to copy; if yes, I can display the content).